# Check whether a line is in the middle of a block comment?

Tags: elisp

When, while executing an emacs-lisp function, point is at the beginning of a line, how can I check whether that line is part of a block comment, inside it, or starting it?

The stupid approach, that I am doing now, is to go to the first non-whitespace character and see if its face is `font-lock-comment-face` or some such:

```
(save-excursion
  (skip-syntax-forward "\\s-")
  (let ((face (get-char-property (point) 'face)))
    (or (eq face 'font-lock-comment-face)
        (eq face 'font-lock-comment-delimiter-face)
        (eq face 'font-lock-doc-face))))
```

But this fails sometimes, because the function that invokes this might be run *before* fontification is performed.

Is there some standard way of doing this? (Please include, if you can, a link to the emacs lisp manual section that I've missed.)

Comment: The first half of this question is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815781/emacs-lisp-and-c-mode-when-am-i-in-a-comment-region/12820339#12820339.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know the standard way of checking if a point is within a comment is by calling [`syntax-ppss`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Position-Parse.html). See [Parser state](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Parser-State.html#Parser-State) for the meaning of its return value.

In particular,

```
(nth 4 (syntax-ppss))
```

is not `nil` when the point is in a comment.

To determine if this is a *block comment*, try checking if the text at the beginning of the comment (position `(nth 8 (syntax-ppss))`) matches a regular expression (for example by using `looking-at`).

Comment: Actually, `(nth 4 (syntax-ppss))` can evaluate to other values than `t` when inside a comment (e.g. an integer).  But it will always be a non-nil value.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @Stefan! I updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome! This inspired to fix a function I use to pull up the next line to the current line: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7519/115