# Which variable gives the value of the current character?

Tags: cursor

Is there a build-in variable which saves the current character at which the cursor is positioned on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `char-after` or `following-char` function to know what's the character under the cursor (or after the point).

More on [`Examing Text Under Point`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Near-Point.html)

> Remember that point is always between characters, and the cursor normally appears over the character following point.

Comment: Based on your suggestion I wrote a function to determine if the current character is "i" or not but it doesn't work. (defun test-i ()
   (interactive)
      ;; Check whether the current character is "i" or not. 
   (if (equal (char-after) 'i)
       (message "yes" )(message "no") )
   )

Comment: `'i` means *symbol* i. What you need is `?i` which returns the decimal ASCII value of the character 'i'.

Comment: Here's what I found on learning about elisp symbols from a quick google search: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1780984/1219634

Comment: On a side note, I prefer using the `looking-at` function that checks if the current character matches my provided regexp. Here is an example of how I use this function to check if the current character is a space character or a comment-start character: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7519/115 For you example use case you can do `(looking-at "i")`.

Comment: *Correction: `looking-at` checks regexp match with current character **onwards**.